# Mysql query on results match doesn't work

Tags: mysql, inner-join

my simple table is formatted in this way (4 fields) and over 100 rows:

id result  id_user       data
1     0     11     2016-10-15 18:00:00 
2     0     13     2016-10-15 18:00:00 
3     0     16     2016-10-15 18:00:00 
4     0     24     2016-10-15 18:00:00 
5     0     6      2016-10-15 18:00:00 
6     3   5      2016-10-15 18:00:00 
7     3     45     2016-10-15 18:00:00
8  3     66     2016-10-15 18:00:00 
9     3     4      2016-10-15 18:00:00 
10     3     33    2016-10-8 17:00:00 
11     1     55    2016-10-8 17:00:00 
12     1     101   2016-10-8 17:00:00

....

I save 10 record every week with this logic:
If a team wins, I'll save 3 point for each member of the team and 0 points to every member of the team looser. (if they draw, I'll save 1 point to all 10 members) and so on.

Now my question is how to extract first 3 player saved in this table, that had played 5 matches at least and, in the last 5 matches, had the major points.

I formatted my query in this way:

```
(SELECT m1.id_user, m1.data, SUM(result) AS ris 
FROM my_table m1 
JOIN(SELECT id_user 
      FROM my_table 
      GROUP BY id_user 
      HAVING COUNT(id_user) >= 5) m2 
ON m2.id_user = m1.id_user 
GROUP BY id_user 
ORDER BY m1.data DESC) 
ORDER BY ris DESC LIMIT 3;
```

But this query consider tha amount of points in all the matches played and not only in the last 5 matches! How can insert, if it is possible, this condition in my query?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a very efficient way to do this, but it is possible, even without MySQL support for windowing functions.  It helps keep it simple that scores are single digits and there are only two possible non-zero scores.

```
select id_user, 
    3*length(replace(replace(left(group_concat(result order by data desc separator ''), 5), '0', ''), '1', ''))
        +length(replace(replace(left(group_concat(result order by data desc separator ''), 5), '0', ''), '3', '')) 
        as score_sum 
from my_table 
group by 1 
having count(*) >= 5 
order by 2 desc 
limit 3;
```

Breaking it down:

`group by 1` is shorthand for `group by id_user` (the first value in the select), so it will return only one row for each user.

`group_concat(result order by data desc separator '')` concatenates all the scores for a user, most recent first, with no separator string added between them, producing a string like '033101003' for a user.  `group_concat` will truncate data after a certain (configurable) length and produce a warning, but that isn't of concern here.

`left(..., 5)` takes the leftmost (most recent) five scores for the user (e.g. '03310').

replace(..., '0', '') removes the 0's, so the above example becomes '331'.

We count how many 3's by taking this string, replacing the 1's with '' (producing '33'), and taking the length (2).

Similarly, we count how many 1's by taking this string, replacing the 3's with '' (producing '1') and taking the length (1).

`3*...+...` computes the sum of scores by adding 3 times the number of 3's to the number of 1's (2*3+1 is a sum of 7 for the latest five scores in 0,3,3,1,0,1,0,0,3).

I took this approach because there were only two non-zero scores to deal with.  If there were more, I would have used a different counting trick.  Instead of removing the numbers I didn't want, I would count the ones I did.  You do this by saying `(length(string)-length(replace(string,searchstring,'')))/length(searchstring)`.  For example. to count the c's in abccbacba, you remove the c's (producting abbaba) and subtract the length of that (6) from the length of the original string (9, getting a result of 3).

Comment: Hi @ysth it works perfectly! But honestly I didn't understand the logic you used to format this query. I hope you can explaine in another way step by step. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes @ysth, now it is very clear! Thanks a lot for your support and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the SUM(result) to the subquery.

SELECT m1.id_user, m1.data, result AS ris FROM my_table m1 
 JOIN(SELECT id_user,**SUM(result) as result** FROM my_table GROUP BY id_user HAVING COUNT(id_user) >= 5) m2 ON m2.id_user = m1.id_user GROUP BY id_user 
 ORDER BY m1.data DESC
 ) ORDER BY ris DESC LIMIT 3;

Comment: Hi @Jeffrey Hitosis, I tried your suggest but its output consider only last 10 record inserted.